# How can I clear Google Cloud Storage(GCS) bucket before travis deploy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-storage, travis-ci

This is my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "node"

cache: npm
script: npm run build

deploy:
  provider: gcs
  access_key_id: $ACCESS_KEY_ID
  secret_access_key: $SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  bucket: $BUCKET_NAME
  skip_cleanup: true
  local_dir: dist
  cache_control: "no-cache,max-age=0"
  on:
    branch: master
```

I'm running a vue project, and I build files with hashed filenames.
So everytime I deployed, the new files such as `app.56785678.js` had been deployed to my bucket.
But the previous version (like `app.12341234.js`) is still in the gcs bucket, which should be deleted.
Is there any way to clear the whole bucket before I deploy?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy to a folder `dist` in this case, the [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/gcs/#deploying-specific-folder) says that it will be cleaned up unless `skip_cleanup` is true, which is your case. Please, try:

```
# ...
deploy:
  # ...
  skip_cleanup: false
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me :(, if I set `skip_cleanup` to false, the deployment will fail. I'm wondering if I should run `gsutil rm` command somewhere...

Comment: Can you indicate how does it fail?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, my travis failed while deploying and this is the error.
`/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/dpl-gcs-1.10.15/lib/dpl/provider/gcs.rb:30:in \`chdir': No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - dist (Errno::ENOENT)`

Comment: I think I should always set `skip_cleanup` to true if I am about to deploy the `dist` folder